# Google Play Alpha & Beta testing with different endpoints or custom parameters

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, android-testing

Google developer support is very clear with:

> **Alpha/Beta availability**
>
> Alpha and beta APKs need to have a higher
> version code than production APKs to be available for testing.
>
> 1. To be available for alpha testers, alpha APKs need to have a higher
>    version code than beta APKs.
> 2. If a beta APK is uploaded with a higher
>    version code than an alpha APK, the alpha version will automatically
>    be deactivated.
> 3. If a Production APK is uploaded with a higher version
>    code than an alpha or beta APK, the alpha and/or beta version will
>    automatically be deactivated.
>
> Alpha testing group users are eligible
> for the alpha, beta, or production version of your app with the
> highest version code that is compatible with their device. Beta
> testing group users are only eligible for the beta or production
> version of your app with the highest version code that is compatible
> with their device.

My question is, is there any way to distinguish Alpha/Beta releases from the Production one with a custom parameter with the same binary or APK? When I mean custom parameter, it would be something like a URL pointing to a testing or production Cloud endpoint.

The problem is that otherwise I have to release different APK's depending on the profile, and also when I publish to production alpha/beta testers would get the update pointing to the production Cloud endpoint having their data in the testing one. I would have to publish a production version followed by another alpha/beta version to solve this, but I find it quite tiresome.

Comment: I think what was currently stated in the support document is the only way to go. This can be a feature request.